# AngularJS - Bind filter with toggle button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of people with true/false skills and I would like to filter the data with buttons related to each skill.

I create the toggle buttons for each skill when I click on it, and I create the filter which shows only the people if skill is true. Both are working.

How can I bind the filters with my toggle buttons? If button is active, filter is active. If not, filter is not.

**Button**

```
 <button id="word" ng-class="{'active-word': wordActive}" ng-click="wordButton()">Word</button>

 app.controller('skillsCtrl', function ($scope) {
      $scope.wordActive = false;
      $scope.wordButton = function() {
      $scope.wordActive = !$scope.wordActive;
 }
```

**Filter**

```
app.filter('wordskills', function () {
  return function (items) {

    var filtered = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      var item = items[i];
      if (item.word == true) {
        filtered.push(item);
      }
    }
    return filtered;

  };
});
```

**View**

```
<div class="container" ng-repeat="person in group | wordskills">
```

Answer (score 0):

On click, you can toggle a variable that you pass to your filter. Then you do only filtering if this variable is true:

```
<button ng-click="word = !word" id="word" ng-class="{'active-word': wordActive}" ng-click="wordButton()">Word</button>

<div class="container" ng-repeat="person in group | wordskills: word">

app.filter('wordskills', function () {
    return function (items, word) {
        return word ? items.filter(el => el.word) : items;
    };
});
app.controller('skillsCtrl', function ($scope) {
      $scope.word = false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Faly, it works exactly as I want! Can I ask you some explanations on this line please : 

`return word ? items.filter(el => el.word) : items;`

I really want to understand the code and I am not familiar with `?` and `el` function

Comment: It's called 'ternary operator'. it returns the left part (wich is items.filter(el => el.word) ) if word is true and the right part (wch is items)  in case word is false, so, it's the equivalent of if (word) { return items.filter(el => el.word) } else { return items }

Comment: All right, after quick research on el and => too, I think I understand the line. Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: Hi Faly, sorry to bother you again but I'm stuck with the controller code. Your solution works well only if $scope.word = false. But I want to do an if statement in order to initialize the statut of my button like : 

if (condition is true) { $scope.word = true} else { $scope.word = false }

But I have this error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Can you help me with that please ?

Comment: Ensure array 'group' is not undefined, try to log it,...or just add the code below to make your filter returning an empty array in case items (that is group) is undefined: if (!items) { return []; } else { return word ? items.filter(...) : items; }